# Give me some javascript exercises please

Tags: javascript

The best way I learn anything is by practice and exercise questions. Right now looking at getting familiar with javascript.
I did some basic exercises , but am unable to find more on the internet.

Can you people give me some questions to practice and learn javascript.
 Nothing complicated, just one liners would do.

Example: "increase the size of an image gradually on mouseover." This example I thought for myself, but am struggling to think of more examples . I am bad at thinking for myself I guess.

I have marginal experience in C# and java .
Reason for learning javascript : to be able to write some firefox extensions

Thanks

Edit: I am looking for simple exercises

Comment: Search SO with `[javascript]` or `[jquery]` tag, but don't look at the answers.

Comment: I see jQuery is becoming another AJAX to JavaScript :D

Comment: questions posted on SO are not exactly what I am looking for...

Answer (score 65):

Answer all Javascript questions on this site.

Comment: This! Not only do you learn, but others benefit =)

Answer (score 8):

Hows about this? http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Comment: I suck at maintaing concentration while reading a book. but i can look at the examples in the book. although I didn't want to look at the answers before the question :-/

Answer (score 8):

As Yi Jiang suggested in the comments, you can take a look at the `[Javascript]` or `[jQuery]` SO tags, and not look at the answers.

I made a web app just for this. It's pretty rough at the moment, but it does let you browse SO questions without looking at the answers (then you can reveal the answers with a click).

[**Browse the SO [Javascript] tag in "flashcard" mode**](http://peter-ajtai.com/examples/php/so.php?tag=javascript)

[**For the SO [jQuery] tag in "flashcard" mode**](http://peter-ajtai.com/examples/php/so.php?tag=jquery)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend these:

http://www.learningjquery.com/

or also try webmonkey dot com