# Practice exercises?

Tags: javascript

Is there anything like: http://nathansjslessons.appspot.com/lesson?id=1000

Something where I can learn and practice javascript? I remember when I was going to start with c++, there was a list of practice exercises for command prompt programs. Anything like that for javascript?

I know the best way to improve is to figure out what I want to do and learn how to do it, but I'm able to do everything I want for the time being, and want to have the ability to do whatever else I want without having to learn it.

Comment: @sacabuche This question may well be a duplicate or off-topic, but the correct way to address that is not by telling the questioner to use Google. PS: I see that a closed SO post is the first Google result for those terms. Maybe that was your point, but that's still a bad way to make it.

Comment: I think this is a good question.  "I want to become a better JavaScript programmer.  Programming community: Are there some sites online that offer JavaScript exercises? What are the best?"

Comment: I think https://www.codecademy.com is the best place to start.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is my prefered [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/index.html)

duplicated questions:

[resource for practical javascript exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631716/resource-for-practical-javascript-exercise)
[Give me some javascript exercises please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589715/give-me-some-javascript-exercises-please)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check it out some time

Comment: Great resource, Marijn Haverbeke did a great job with the book and the site!